# Adjusted formatting in Bib. halfway through citations

Tags: bibliographies

I have a report style document in latex in which I have 101 citations.

Here's my setup:

```
% General layout and formatting bib, etc
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

% Packages for figures
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
```

I adjust the margins after the title page with

```
% Before title page
% Adjust header w/ page numbering
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\fancyhf{}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, headspace=0.5in]{geometry}

% After title page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{left=1.5in}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % Remove header line
```

However in my bib. the lefthand margin gets updated 7 pages in, as you can see in this image.

[image]

I insert the bib as follows:

```
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{seamann}
\newpage
```

Any suggestions on resolving or updating the lefthand margin back to 1.5in?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show the bibentry for 37...

Comment: @book{li_structural_2019,
 title = {Structural Modeling of Lymphocyte Receptors and Their Antigens},
 volume = {2048},
 booktitle = {Methods in Molecular Biology},
 author = {Li, Songling and Wilamowski, Jan and Teraguchi, Shunsuke and van Eerden, Floris J. and Rozewicki, John and Davila, Ana and Xu, Zichang and Katoh, Kazutaka and Standley, Daron M.},
 date = {2019},
 doi = {10.1007/978-1-4939-9728-2_17},
 note = {{ISSN}: 19406029},
}

Comment: You must not use `_` on normal text. An error in the .log file will inform you about this. You could escape it or choose a bibliography style which properly formats the doi as an url

Comment: Change the DOI to use ``\_``.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved: In my bibentry for 37, the doi number had an "_" underscore. This attempted to make a subscript "1". Changing to a "-" dash resolved the issue.

Thanks :)

Comment: This solves the error, but you change the DOI, so it won't lead to anything and is useless.

Comment: If you are lucky the altered doi will just cause an error, in the worst case it will lead to a different article.

Comment: Changing the DOI will most likely have unintended consequences. I couldn't test it for lack of a proper MWE, but many styles interface with `hyperref`, which makes `_` and other usually special characters safe in URLs, so that loading `\usepackage{hyperref}` in your preamble may resolve the issue without changing the DOI.